# Least Square Method to fit into an exponential function

Tags: numerical-methods, regression, least-squares, linear-regression

I have some x and y data, and I need to fit those data to $y = \alpha xe^{\beta x}$, using linear least squares regression. If it was $y = \alpha e^{\beta x}$, I could take the natural logarithm of both sides, and solve it like it is $y=mx+b$. But in this question when I do that the result is
$$\ln y=\ln \alpha+\ln x+\beta x.$$
which is not linear. The question wants us to solve it specifically with linear least squares regression. What can I do?

Comment: $\ln x$ and $\ln y$ are data values and $\ln\alpha$ can be represented as $u$ a new independent variable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My attempt:

$$ ln y = ln \alpha + ln x + \beta x $$
$$ ln \frac{y}{x} = ln \alpha + \beta x $$

where $$Z= ln  \frac{y}{x} , \beta_0= ln \alpha \quad and \quad \beta_1 = \beta $$

then, we can write the expression like:
$$Z = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x$$

Comment: $m =  \frac{N Σ(xy) − Σx Σy}{N Σ(x^2) − (Σx)^2}$ can I still use this formula? 
$y\Rightarrow Z,\beta_1\Rightarrow M,x\Rightarrow x$ like this

Comment: It's correct ...